# Postgres pg_stat_activity is it normal if there are duplicate activity?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

like on a picture sometime show error ERROR: SORRY, TOO MANY CLIENTS if i reset my programm the error not appear
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjr9L.png)

i used sequeize orm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ3JB.png)

where i change pool max to 1 pg_stats_activity not duplicated

is it error in postgres or error in my code programm?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal for two reasons: your clients/workers can simply issue the same queries at the same time, plus, if any of the running statements is split into multiple parallel workers on the db, they'll show up multiple times in [`pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW). You can inspect the `leader_pid` column:

> `leader_pid` integer
>
> Process ID of the parallel group leader if this process is a parallel query worker, or process ID of the leader apply worker if this process is a parallel apply worker. NULL indicates that this process is a parallel group leader or leader apply worker, or does not participate in any parallel operation.

On top of that, you can see the last query from each connection with state `idle` even though it already finished.

> `state` text
>
> Current overall state of this backend. Possible values are:
>
> - `active`: The backend is executing a query.
> - `idle`: The backend is waiting for a new client command.
> - `idle in transaction`: The backend is in a transaction, but is not currently executing a query.
> - `idle in transaction (aborted)`: This state is similar to idle in transaction, except one of the statements in the transaction caused an error.
> - `fastpath function call`: The backend is executing a fast-path function.
> - `disabled`: This state is reported if [`track_activities`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-statistics.html#GUC-TRACK-ACTIVITIES) is disabled in this backend.